# SOAP Services in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, soap

When you want to create a SOAP web service in VS 2012, there is no project for this purpose and you must change the target framework to .NET framework 3.5.

I wanted to know that why SOAP service project is not available in .NET Framework 4 and newer versions? Is using SOAP service deprecated and restful web services preferred by Microsoft?

Comment: Use the WCF Service Application or WCF Service Library for SOAP services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP is an interoperability protocol which is not deprecated. There's no such thing as SOAP project in Visual Studio.

In previous versions of .NET you could have created ASP.NET Web Services (you know the stuff with `[WebMethod]` and the `.asmx` extension). Those ASP.NET WebServices were using SOAP as transport protocol. They are deprecated. That's why there's no longer this option in newer versions.

Couple of alternatives:

- ASP.NET Web API (for more RESTful stuff)
- WCF (if you need to support things like SOAP or other binary protocols)

Comment: You mean that ASP.NET Web services that uses SOAP is now deprecated but the SOAP itself is not! So what is the new Project in Visual studio that is used to create a project that uses SOAP?

Comment: No, ASP.NET WebServices are not deprecated **now**. They have been deprecated for a **very long time**. You could use WCF instead if you want to develop a SOAP based web service.

Comment: @PooyaYazdani - More accurately, the old .ASMX web servcies are deprecated (and I believe no longer supported by MS).

Answer (score 2):

That's right. You won't get a project template in VS to create a SOAP service.  Maybe you will find an online template for this in the community. Yet, you can easily create a SOAP service from a WCF service template which is the de facto web service technology in .net and it's extremely flexible